# How write a .bat file which open some of short cuts on my desktop?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have some short cuts and files on the desktop and I want to open those at a time by .bat file. How do I do that?

Comment: As a note for the future: Please take care to write properly. While we don't expect perfect English, we expect questions to not contain txtspeek such as 'u', 'r', or '2' as abbreviations for 'you', 'are' and 'too'. =)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
start %userprofile%\Desktop\your.lnk
```

That should execute your link.

Comment: No I would not add this line for a one line script. It is also possible to add an at sign at the first position :)